# Cleanest solution to extract prepared statement logic

Tags: java, database, prepared-statement, encapsulation

I wanted to encapsulate batching and connection logic into an own class, shown in the code below, to enforce that connection is closed properly and make application logic easier.

```
public class SQLHelper {
    public static void insertBatched(List<String> insertStatements) {
        // do connection and batching logic here
    }
}
public class Application {
    public static void doWork() {
        // create insert statements here
        SQLHelper.insertBatched(statements);
    }
}
```

The problem is that building insert Statements as Strings is bad practice and should be replaced with using prepared statements. When using prepared statements I need to to set the parameters as well as doing batching on the same object, so share it between two classes. Solutions which I have thought of so far:

1. Getting the connection from the SQLHelper and using it to prepare the statement. The problem with this solution is that passing connections between classes is error prone because proper resource releasing can't be ensured
2. Pass in a string to SQLHelper and getting a prepared statement. Problem with that is that the application has to batch the insert statement in this case and again connection closing

Both solutions have drawbacks so I wanted to ask **what is the cleanest design solution to get maximum encapsulation**, while still have safety about proper resource realeasing.

Comment: Read about connection pooling. This is much better than opening and closing connections.

Comment: @SajithSilva Connection pools (at least the ones I know) are fairly transparent so there's no difference in application code between the pooled/unpooled version.

Comment: Use Spring's JdbcTemplate (or reinvent it): http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#jdbc

Comment: And the batching code best remains in the application part?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage SQL connections manually, I suppose you could use something like this

```
interface SqlWorker {
    public void run(Connection c);
}


class SQLHelper {
    public void execute(SqlWorker worker) throws SQLException {
        Connection c = //Get the connection
        try {
            worker.run(c);
        } finally {
            c.close();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    new SQLHelper().execute((c) -> {
        //do any connection sql stuff here. DB helper will clean up.
    });
}
```

With this pattern you would not have to pass the connections around.
But its very easy to do something stupid and crash it. Also If you create a prepared statement or open a ResultSet, those needs to be explicitly close.

Managing your connections problematically is a pain and you may want to consider using spring/JPA like frameworks so connections/transactions are managed.